# Can Angular Renderer2 setStyle function operate on an element where the style attribute is not yet defined?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-renderer2

In an Angular application let's suppose we have a body element as

```
<body>
   ...
</body>
```

and now I want to set its background to some value using Angular Renderer2 as

```
this.renderer.setStyle(document.body, 'background', 'url("some-example-url");');
```

and nothing happens.

But now if I do it using setAttribute function as

```
this.renderer.setAttribute(document.body, 'style', 'background: url("some-example-url");');
```

this will work out fine.

My question is: can setStyle function operate on an element where the style attribute is not yet defined ?

Comment: After some further testing I ended up setting style attribute in my body element in the ngOnInit function as

`ngOnInit() {  this.renderer.setAttribute(document.body, 'style', ''); }`

then set my style using setStyle as mentioned in the question above. Turns out it worked out fine. Now if anybody has a concise and clear answer about this function design I'll be glad to read it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what the problem was in my code. Using setStyle with a semicolon-ended string as a value does not work.

```
// Bad
this.renderer.setStyle(document.body, 'background', 'url("some-example-url");');
// Good
this.renderer.setStyle(document.body, 'background', 'url("some-example-url")');
```

And after a deeper dive in Angular source code, especially in the [platform-browser implementation of renderer](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d1ea1f4c7f3358b730b0d94e65b00bc28cae279c/packages/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_renderer.ts#L226) it does not matter if a style attribute is set or not. Angular seems to handle it anyway.